# How to hide scroll bars from iframe?

Tags: jquery, css, html, iframe

I'm getting scroll bars with my iframe inside fancy box and don't know to remove them I tried everything

example: http://jsfiddle.net/t4j3C/

nothing seems to work what am i doing wrong?  i tried the codes below and they wouldn't work either.

```
iframe { overflow: hidden; }

<iframe ... scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Comment: What browser and version are you using? I don't see scrollbars in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `fancybox.css` is specifying the `overflow-y: scroll` which is forcing the scroll bar.  You can force the override with `!important`:

```
.fancybox-overlay, .fancybox-overlay-fixed {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t4j3C/3/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe can try this:

```
<iframe ... scrollable="no"></iframe>
```

or like Greg suggested to override the default css by using !important:

```
.fancybox-overlay, .fancybox-overlay-fixed {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

Hope it helps!